# Merge multiple tables in sas using loop or macro

Tags: sas

I have generated the tables of Forecast_2013 to 2022 in a loop and then merged all datasets in to 1 Table. But now I want to do merge the datasets in a loop with irrespective of years, The next year will be 2023 or 2024...I dont want to do mannually to set Forecast_2023;set forecast_2024. How can I put in to loop using macro?

```
Data P_OT.FORECAST(DROP=td qq AGE1 AGE2 AGE3 AGE4  AGEBANDFCST020 AGEBANDFCST030 AGEBANDFCST035P
     HSI1_2012 HSI1_2013 HSI1_2014 HSI1_2015 HSI1_2016 HSI1_2017 HSI1_2018 HSI1_2019 HSI1_2020  HSI1_2021 HSI1_2022);

set FORECAST_2013;set FORECAST_2014;set FORECAST_2015;set FORECAST_2016;
set FORECAST_2017;set FORECAST_2018;set FORECAST_2019;set FORECAST_2020;
set FORECAST_2021;set FORECAST_2022;
run;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are merging? The code you have posted will just stack your datasets into one. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Yes Scott, I want to stack

Comment: Your code is different from scott's, in that you have many SET statements and he has one SET statement.  Your code would interleave the rows, and stop when one dataset ran out of rows (not the last dataset).  Scott's would output all rows and not interleave.

Comment: Yes, I tried Scott code, But Its not working Joe

Comment: I edited to drop the variables you wanted, but I am on my phone, so I'll let joe take over if he wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to what Scott posted would be:

```
*Assign library to folder where FORECAST_ files are located;
libname NAME 'C:\Path to Folder';

*Data step to stack files;
Data P_OT.FORECAST(DROP=td qq AGE1 AGE2 AGE3 AGE4  AGEBANDFCST020 
    AGEBANDFCST030 AGEBANDFCST035P HSI1_:);
    set NAME.FORECAST_:;
run;
```

This should give the same results as what Scott posted using name prefix lists instead of using SQL to produce lists of datasets to be merged and variables to be dropped.

The code above will stack all datasets in the libname library that start with "FORECAST_". It will also drop all variables in the created dataset that begin with "HSI1_".

Answer (score 0):

You can use proc sql and the sashelp.vcolumn table to find the names of all your tables and create a macro variable containing them.  To do this all your tables need to be in the same library, and any other tables in the library can not contain `FORCAST_`.  The part of the sql code that says memname like '%FORECAST_%' is doing a search on all the tables in the library called `libname` to select the tables that contain `FORCAST_`.  The sql step creates a list of your tables that you can then inject into your data step to stack them.

Again: Be careful there are not other tables with the name like `FORECAST_` or it will try to stack tables you do not want. The easiest way to ensure this would be to put them in their own library when you create these tables.

If you have all these tables in the work library then replace `libname` with `work`

I'm on my phone and haven't checked the substr and index part, but if i recall correctly that should work.

```
proc sql noprint;

    select "libname."||memname
    into :stack_tables separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = upper("libname")
        and
            memname like '%FORECAST_%'
    ;

    select "HSI1_"||substr(memname,index(memname,"_")+1,4)
    into :drop_vars separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = upper("libname")
        and
            memname like '%FORECAST_%'
    ;
quit;

Data P_OT.FORECAST(DROP=td qq AGE1 AGE2 AGE3 AGE4  AGEBANDFCST020 AGEBANDFCST030 AGEBANDFCST035P
     &drop_vars.);
    set &stack_tables.;
run;
```

Comment: and also I want to drop a column HSI1_2023, IF the table is set to Forecast_2023

Comment: is there an HSI1_ variable that you drop for each table? following the form HSI1_year?

Comment: yes, Table Forecast_2013 will have HSI1_2013... Forecast_2023 will have  HSI1_2023, Have to drop.